# Where to find a list of US stocks with monthly expiration options only?

Tags: united-states, options

Does anybody know where to find a list of US stocks with monthly expiration options only (no weeklies plz) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CBOE used to provide nice simple symbol directories for equity options, index options, LEAP options, etc. but not anymore.  I haven't found anything comparable for a number of years.

What you can do is download and import the complete list of equity options into Excel from [here](https://www.cboe.com/us/options/symboldir/equity_index_options/).

Then, download the complete list of weekly options from [here](https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/#:%7E:text=List%20of%20Available%20Weekly%20Options%20%20%20,%20%2006%2F02%2F21%20%209%20more%20rows%20).

Merge the two lists and delete the duplicates and you'll have a list stocks and ETFs that only offer monthly options.

Note that every symbol on the complete list of options will offer monthly options.  Some will offer weekly options as well.  Out of curiosity, why are you interested in stocks that do not offer weekly options?  You could just ignore the weeklies and trade the monthlies.

Comment: Dear Bob, thank you for this approach, it's very clear and efficient. I knew about weeklies and their list on the CBOE which I had found by search engines but did not find the list of the "rest" (aka monthly). Now, I can complete the whole spectra. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a list is freely available from official sources.

However, the opposite of what you are looking for — a list of US stocks that have weekly options — is available from the Options Clearing Corporation (OCC): [Weekly and Quarterly Options](https://www.theocc.com/Market-Data/Market-Data-Reports/Series-and-Trading-Data/Weekly-and-Quarterly-Options) ([CSV download](https://marketdata.theocc.com/weekly-options?action=download)).

To get the list of US stocks that have no weekly options, you could use the OCC's list of stocks that have weekly options to filter the list of all optionable US securities (also downloadable from the OCC's website: [Directory of Listed Products](https://www.theocc.com/Market-Data/Market-Data-Reports/Series-and-Trading-Data/Directory-of-Listed-Products)).